# How to delete nifi flowfiles from the queue?

Tags: apache-nifi

PDF files flow to routeOnAttribute which filters files in file size. So now I have greater than file size and less than file size. With the greater than file size going to S3 bucket and than flow to success.
So what I want is to delete / remove the flowfiles from the queue as we are not doing anything with the flowfiles.

Can anyone able to guide me on which processor should I use.

Answer (score 0):

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#relationships-tab

If a Relationship is auto-terminated, any FlowFile that is routed to that Relationship will be removed from the flow and its processing considered complete.

[image]